# React does not show css style in nested <a></a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am starting with react and I would like to make simple navigation bar for beginning.
I am using component for item in the list of links. Which is used in the component with whole list and than it´s rendered by another component.

This is one item in the list.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class NavLi extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <li className="nav-item active"><a className="nav-link" href={this.props.href}>{this.props.children}</a></li>
    );
}
}
```

Called by this class:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import NavLi from './NavLi';

export default class NavUl extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            <NavLi href="home">Home</NavLi>
            <NavLi href="about">About</NavLi>
            <NavLi href="contact">Contact</NavLi>
        </ul>
    );
}
}
```

And again and again.

```
import Log from './Log';
import NavUl from './NavUl';

export default class Nav extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
            <div className="container">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">ProjectName</a>
                <NavUl/>
                <Log/>
            </div>
        </nav>

    );
}
}
```

.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Nav from './navbar/Nav';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Nav/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

This whole thing is in .html like this: `<div id="react"></div>`

I am using bootsrtap4 and the problem is, that in every item in the list of navigation bar I can´t see css class at `<a></a>` when I run the app. Everything worsk fine, but in tags `<a></a>` are no classess  at all after running this app [screenshot from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyCJP.png).

Any advice why this is not working? Thank you.

Comment: Your 2 classes have name `NavLi`

Comment: I haven´t noticed, thank you, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, that's why i've added it as comment, not answer :)

Comment: Your code actually works. [Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1748/)

Answer (score 3):

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model:
>   Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.

Nested `<a>` elements are forbidden in HTML. You are bouncing off error recovery in the browser.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, I tried to move `<a></a>` outside of the `<li>`, but it did not solve the problem. Weird thing is, that if I have it like this in clean .html, it works fine.

Comment: In that case, checkout your dev tools to see what html output you'll get. It might be somewhat different then you expect

Comment: There is a screenshot at the end of the question. The class attribute just  disappears from `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't define the style in CSS file. 
Can you find a style of 'nav-link' in CSS file? 
In my case, the class did not appear when I don't define the style in CSS file.